# c# creating new unique instances of objects

Tags: c#, memory

My question is how do I change the following code to create 10 different instances of objects instead of 10 of the same Object.

```
 List <OBJ> newList = new List<OBJ> ();
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     OBJ newOBJ = new OBJ (i);
     newList.Add(newOBJ);  
 }
```

Where the OBJ class is:

```
 class OBJ    {
    public static int numb;

    public OBJ(int i)
    {
        numb = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of `numb` being static?

Comment: No reason, it's a bug. And no this is not homework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That are 10 different objects. But since the number is [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx), they all have the same number.

So make it non-static if you want.

```
class OBJ    {
    public int numb;

    public OBJ(int i)
    {
        numb = i;
    }
}
```

If you want to count the number of instances, you can leave it as static.

```
class OBJ    {
    public static int num_instances;
    public int number;

    public OBJ(int i)
    {
        number = i;
        num_instances ++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make `numb` an *instance* field instead of a *class* field. Remove the `static`:

```
public int numb;
```

When `static` all instances of `OBJ` use the same `int` named `numb`.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

That is what your code is doing already. the `static` keyword on your `numb` member makes numb shared across all instances of `OBJ`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that i understand your question but try remove the static keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you use `new`, you get a new instance. The code seems ok. The only problem is that you should REMOVE `static` from `public static int numb`.

```
class OBJ    {
  public int numb;

  public OBJ(int i)
  {
      numb = i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new instances, but your only property is static which gets shared among all instances.

Answer (score 0):

You should only remove the `static` keyword...take a look to this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx(v=vs.100).aspx